# Eclipse cannot find my Nexus S on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

I followed the tutorial for "MyFirstApp" from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) and was able to get 'hello world' up and running on an emulator. However, when it comes time to run the app on the device, Eclipse and adb cannot detect the Nexus S on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. I followed the instructions to install google USB driver using the Android SDK manager.

How do deploy an app using eclipse to my Nexus S?

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial on Android forget to include a very important detail in getting the Nexus S to work with Windows 7 64 bit. Following the instructions from [this link](http://kaustubhghanekar.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-64-bit-drivers-on-windows-7.html). After you download the Google USB drivers, you need to install it on device manager.

According to the link,

> Right Click Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Right click you Nexus -> Update Driver -> "Browse my Computer for Driver Software" -> Browse path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" also tick "Include sub folders"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you guys.

For others with Nexus 7. Apart from the instructions in the Eclipse 'MyFirst.App' tutorial.
Even if you believe you have the latest google driver, go and get it from.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top

Then browse to it from the Update Drivers, for your device Nexus. If your Nexus is connected you will see a pop up asking about the new device on it's USB port.

It did not appear in Eclipse straight away, but press 'Run' anyway, now it appears on the list of devices so you can select it. It ran successfully fro there.